# memory card is not show in recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, sd-card

can you please suggest me. memory card is not showing in recovery mode how to solve this problem because i want to install android lollipop in my Samsung ace duos 6802.

Answer (score 1):

In recovery, go to `mounts` and make sure `ext_sdcard` or similar is check-marked.

Also try disabling/enabling `MTP Mode` (if you are on twrp) in `mounts` if it still doesn't mount along with above step. Cant say how is that related, but this did the trick once for me.